# Can't run vagrant, getting 'Could not find class php for vagrant.vm on node vagrant.vm'

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I've inherited a web project from another developer, it is built in Laravel and was set up to use Vagrant.

I've installed the latest Vagrant, and when I run `vagrant up` it runs through the usual steps, until it throws the following error:

```
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: Error: Could not find class php for vagrant.vm on node vagrant.vm
==> default: Error: Could not find class php for vagrant.vm on node vagrant.vm
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

My `default.pp` file is as follows:

```
    ensure => present,
}

exec { 'apt-get update':
    command => '/usr/bin/apt-get update',
}

# Include our classes
hiera_include('classes')

package { 'nano':
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

# Set up nginx
package { 'nginx':
    ensure => present,
    require => Exec['apt-get update'],
}

service { 'nginx':
    ensure => running,
    require => Package['nginx'],
}

file { 'default-nginx-disable':
    path => '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default',
    ensure => absent,
    require => Package['nginx'],
}

file { 'nginx-vhost':
    path => '/etc/nginx/sites-available/vhost.conf',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/nginx/vhost',
    require => File['default-nginx-disable']
}

file { 'vagrant-nginx-enable':
    path => '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf',
    target => '/etc/nginx/sites-available/vhost.conf',
    ensure => link,
    notify => Service['nginx'],
    require => [
        File['nginx-vhost'],
    ],
}

class { '::mysql::server':
    root_password => 'mysqlpass'
}

class { '::mysql::bindings':
    php_enable => true
}

class { 'elasticsearch':
    java_install => true,
    manage_repo  => true,
    repo_version => '5.x'
}

elasticsearch::instance { 'es-01': }
```

Comment: Your problem is not with Vagrant but with Puppet. I’m not familiar with Puppet, but there is only one mention of PHP, a proper setup is absent. But then, the file is incomplete.